# Makefile. Multidimensional list?

Tags: makefile

I need to write a pattern rule for the following case:

- There are 2 folders: `A` and `B`
- Running the command `python gen.py --a=A/file1.foo --b=file2.bar --c=file3.bar` generates `B/file1.foo`
- `file1`, `file2` and `file3` are different strings

Is there a way to group those filenames in some kind of a multidimensional array, so that all files are written exactly once (I'll use python syntax):

```
files = [["a1.foo", "a2.bar", "a3.bar"],
         #...200 other groups...
         ["b1.foo", "b2.bar", "b3.bar"]]
```

and then the rule looks like this:

```
$(files): B/{reference 1 elem}: A/{1 elem} {2 elem} {3 elem}
    python gen.py --a=A/{1 elem} --b={2 elem} --c={3 elem}
```

Any ideas how to archive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard make syntax for that:

```
all :

targets :=
define add_target
B/${1}: A/${1} ${2} ${3}
targets += B/${1}
endef

# Build dependencies.
$(eval $(call add_target,a1.foo,a2.bar,a3.bar)) 
# ...
$(eval $(call add_target,b1.foo,b2.bar,b3.bar))

# One generic rule for all ${targets}     
${targets} : % :
    @echo Making $@ from $^

all : ${targets}

.PHONY: all
```

Note that these `$(eval $(call add_target,...)` are white-space sensitive, do not insert spaces in there.

If you would like `make` to create the directory for outputs automatically do:

```
${targets} : % : | B

B :
    mkdir $@
```

Comment: B/${1}: A/${1} ${2} ${3} | How can I append all arguments that left (in case there's more then 3 of them)? And where can I read more about it? I haven't found anything relevant about it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a little repetition isn't so bad really

```
targets := B/a1.foo B/b1.foo

.PHONY: all

all: $(targets)

$(targets): B/%: A/%
    python gen.py --a=$< --b=$(word 2,$^) --c=$(word 3,$^)

B/a1.foo: a2.bar a3.bar
B/b1.foo: b2.bar b3.bar
```